# Remove element from react-native navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

Just wondering how I can remove the (Back) text in navigation and just use the arrow for navigating I am using react native expo.

```
 <Stack.Screen
    name="ChatRoom"
    component={ChatRoomScreen}
    options={({route}) => ({
    
      title: route.params.name, 
      
      headerRight: () => (
        <View 
        style={{
          flexDirection: "row",
          width: 100,
          justifyContent: "space-between",
          marginRight: 10,
        }}
      >
     
          <MaterialIcons name="call" size={22} color={'white'} />
          <FontAwesome5 name="video" size={22} color={'white'} />
          <MaterialCommunityIcons name="dots-vertical" size={22} color={'white'}/>
        </View>
      )
    })}
  />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found that react navigation behaves weirdly sometimes. But first, you can try this:

```
headerBackTitle: ' ',
```

if that makes the back arrow missing, you can add it manually like so:

```
headerBackImage: ()=> (<Icon name='chevron-left' color='#FFFFF' onPress={()=>{ navigation.goBack();}} />),
```

you also need to make sure your options has navigation like so:

```
options={({route, navigation}) => ({
```

Note: the Icon i used it from react-native-elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to

```
headerBackTitleVisible: false,
```

add this to `options` like

```
options={{
...
headerBackTitleVisible: false,
}}
```

Proof: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#headerbacktitlevisible